# restheart - connections not closed

Tags: mongodb, restheart

Is there a way to set a timeout on connection from restheart to mongodb?  Looking on the server it seems there is a large number of connections that stay open for an extended period of time.  We are using restheart 1.1 and mongodb 3.2.

I noticed there are a couple of settings added in the documentation for restheart 2.0 (IDLE_TIMEOUT, NO_REQUEST_TIMEOUT) but these are not in the 1.X documentation and 2.0 is currently in Beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection options added to restheart 2.0 are related to incoming HTTP requests and not to the connection between restheart and mongodb.

To set the connection options toward mongodb you can specify them in the mongo-uri configuration option.

Refer to [connection string options](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-options) in mongodb documentation for more information.